# Selenium WebDriver how to insert text into field

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I'm designing tests in Selenium WebDriver Framwework and I would like to insert text into fields in login box.

Here is a website www.fitandjump-widzew.pl
After click on "Zaloguj" button in top right corner, Login box appears.
I would like to insert text into E-mail inputfield.

Here is my code:

```
WebElement emailInput =   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id=\"inputFields\"]"));
emailInput.click();
emailInput.sendKeys("grzegorzrudniak@gmail.com");
```

After execution I get this error:
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Can anyone help me to insert text into this field?
Please take a look at second input in this box, it's called "Hasło".
Xpath of this two fields is the same. 
Additional question is how to insert text into "Hasło" inputfield as well?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure the locator you are using identifies single element [Unique]. Use single quotes in xpath and use correct xpath, you haven't used any html tag after `//` I've used * which means it is valid for all HTML tags.

```
WebElement emailInput =   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='inputFields']"));
//emailInput.click(); // no need to click on the element, you can directly type.
emailInput.sendKeys("grzegorzrudniak@gmail.com");
```

Comment: Solved it by this WebElement emailInput = driver.findElement(By.name("login_email"));
        emailInput.sendKeys("grzegorzrudniak@gmail.com");